# How to link up users in Firebase to information defined in other Java classes?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase database currently looks like this.

**Main Branch 1**
(Users' Information)

```
{Users
      Individual Users
                   Username, Email, Password}
```

**Main Branch 2** (To-Dos)

```
{Event, Description}
```

The issue now is that even though I can authenticate users, whenever I log into the app, users are not tagged to their to-dos within the app. Hence, the to-dos are always static.

Ideally, I would like to either:

1)Keep the branches and tag the main branch 2 to main branch 1 based on a certain type of authentication (most probably username, as it is unique)

2) Incorporate main branch 2 into main branch 1 and just have it look like this.

```
{Users
    Individual Users
        Username, Email, Password
            {Event
                Description}
}
```

I have a feeling that option 2 would be both easier to implement, as well as less messy to manage the app in the future.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The to-do branch can be like this:

```
to-do
  userID
    randomID
       name: userX
       event: Meeting
       Description: meeting about the next project with usery
  userID
    randomID
        name: userG
        event: football match
        Description: Watch the match with my children
```

Thus the `userid` and `name` are now linked with the events.

Comment: I see... Meaning like how I phrased it earlier? Keep the two branches (userinfo /  event + description) separate but include a userid for each event / description?

Comment: just make one branch for userinfo and another branch called `to-do` as the one in the answer. Why do you want to make an event+description branch alone if each event is associated with a user?